# Why can't I access the value of a public variable in a PHP5 class from class functions?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.0 with PHP5.3.2 on Apache 2.2.14 with MySQL 5.1.48-community. I created a small test controller to isolate another problem and discovered that my problem appears to be caused by public variable accessibility. Calling test1 or test2 will result in errors because they can't see the value of the array elements set in the other functions. Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work? If so, what is the solution as I need to be able to access class-wide variables.

Thanks.

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
  public $data;

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data = array();
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->data['test1'] = 'This is a test of class public variable access.<br />';         
    echo 'Class index() called.<br />';
    echo $this->data['test1'];  
  }

  function test1()
  {
    $this->data['test2'] = 'This is a second test of the class public variable access.<br />';          
    echo 'Class test1 called.<br />';
    echo $this->data['test1'];  
    echo $this->data['test2'];  
  }

  function test2()
  {
    echo 'The data array contains these two entries:<br />';
    echo $this->data['test1'];  
    echo $this->data['test2'];  
  }
}
/* End of file test.php*/
/* Location: */
```

Comment: How and in what order are these called and what's the output?

Comment: What's the exact wording of the error messages?

Comment: Can't tell from looking at this code... need CI_Controller, and the error message details.

Comment: The error message is: [code]A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: test1

Filename: controllers/test.php

Line Number: 26
[/code]

Comment: It is definitely something in CodeIgniter code as I can create an instance of the class -- $test = new Test; and call the functions and everything works.

Comment: I guess line 26 is in `test1()`? Are you always calling `index()` before calling `test1()`? Because the index *is* undefined unless you do.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your code. When you `__construct()` the class, `$this->data` is equal to `array()`. An empty array. The only line that should work is the last one in your `test1()` function.

Remove all the echo statements from `index()` and `test1()` and try this:

```
  function test2()
  {
      $this->index();
      $this->test1();
      echo 'The data array contains these two entries:<br />';
      echo $this->data['test1'];  
      echo $this->data['test2'];  
    }
```

This should work because now you have defined those array keys by *running the function that defines them.*

Try defining them in your `__construct` if you need access to them in every method of the class.

Comment: The problem, as it turns out, is caused by the fact that CodeIgniter creates a new controller object instance every time a function is called instead of properly creating a singleton object. Thus each call to different functions is working on a different object and different data which means that whatever data was stored by previous functions is not available.

Comment: I suggest you answer you own question and accept it because you're absolutely right :)

Comment: @user I don't know the specifics of CI, but usually there's only one controller action called per request. Unless you're explicitly calling several methods in one request, it's not a matter of singleton objects, but of data persistence between requests (which *doesn't* happen in PHP just like this).